# Weird behaviour of UIButton with tintColor on enabled/disabled states

Tags: ios7, uibutton, tintcolor

**UPDATE:**

Even `UIBarButtonItem`s do not respond to state change, visually.

**The scenario:**

I have a `UIButton` of type `UIButtonTypeSystem` initialized as below:

```
sendButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];

sendButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[sendButton setTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(SEND_BUTTON_COLOR)];

sendButton.opaque = YES;

sendButton.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = NO;

sendButton.frame = CGRectMake(275, 6, 50, 35);

UIImage* sendImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"toilet_paper"];

[sendButton setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:sendImage.CGImage scale:sendImage.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationLeft]
            forState:UIControlStateNormal];

sendButton.enabled = NO;

[sendButton addTarget:self action:@selector(post) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

**The Purpose:**

It is associated with a `UITextView` such that it is set to `enabled` if there is some text in the `textView` AND my host is available (checked through Reachability) and it's `enabled` property is changed in `textViewDidChange:` delegate method with the following:

```
sendButton.enabled = [APP_DELEGATE hostAvailable] && [myTextView.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" \n"]].length > 0;
```

According to this `enabled` state, the button must toggle between `SEND_BUTTON_COLOR` (`enabled` = YES) and `grayColor` (`enabled` = NO).

**The Problem:**

Up until now, the code used to work fine. It was gray when there was no text in the textView and it became `SEND_BUTTON_COLOR` as soon as there was some text in the textView. However, out of the blue, it has stopped this behaviour. What happens is, it stays gray all the time irrespective of the content of the textView. Once it is pressed, it becomes `SEND_BUTTON_COLOR` and stays that way, again irrespective of the textView text.

How do I regain the behaviour of the button I used to have on my `UIButton`?

Comment: Is the `enabled` state changing? Or is it only the `tintColor`?

Comment: The `enabled` state changes. It's only the `tintColor` that does not respond. I removed the `UIAppearance` code I had added recently to change `titleTextAttributes`, but did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you show the code where you are toggling the color?

Comment: I am not toggling the color. I'm toggling the `enabled` state. It's all in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. When the `enabled` state changes, how do you change the color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it appears, the problem was on my part. I had subclassed `UIButton` in the .m file of a different VC (not imported by the VC in question, or any other VCs it had imported):

```
@implementation UIButton (Border)

- (void) setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled {

    if (enabled) {

        self.layer.borderColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x888888).CGColor;

    } else {

        self.layer.borderColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xdddddd).CGColor;
    }

    [super setEnabled:enabled];

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

@end
```

Somehow, this interfered with my button. After weeks of further subclassing, changing images, changing titles, etc, I was able to diagnose the issue (accidentally) by jumping to definition (`CMD` + `Click`) of the `enabled` method, and it took me straight to the source of the issue (the subclass code). Commented it out, and voila. Things were back to normal.

I hope this helps someone in the future who faces the same issue (or makes the same mistake I did).

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your button's tint color again in the textViewDidChange delegate method.

In your delegate where you are setting the enabled state:

```
sendButton.enabled = [APP_DELEGATE hostAvailable] && [myTextView.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" \n"]].length > 0;
if(sendButton.enabled){
  [sendButton setTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(SEND_BUTTON_COLOR)];
}
else{
    //Set Another Color For Disabled State
}
```

Comment: It's an image, on the button, not text. If it were, things would be easier. I'm asking about default `tintColor` behavior of a `UIButton` which is dependent on it's `enabled` state.